# Looping through cell

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm drawing squares on a grid. The squares need to have an ID as set within a cell array. I was expecting the ID to loop through each ID in the cell in order by instead it cycles through in rows.

[image: Matlab expected and actual results]

```
cell_id = cell(1, 2); % 1 x 5 cell array
cell_id{1, 1} = 1365; cell_id{1, 2} = 1256; cell_id{1, 3} = 6214; cell_id{1, 4} = 2587; cell_id{1, 5} = 1564;

hold on

for i = 1:2:12

count = 1;

for ii = 1:2:12

    plot(1*i , 1*ii, 's', 'MarkerSize', 50);

    if (count <= 5)
        id = cell_id(1,count);
        text(1*i, 1*ii, ['ID:',id]);
        count = count + 1;
    elseif (count > 5)
        id = cell_id(1,1);
        count = 1;
        text(1*i, 1*ii, ['ID:',id]);
    end   
  end
end
```

Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: Why is that your expected output? We need more details in order to know what the algorithm should do.

Comment: @JaviV, the squares are RF boxes and the ID represents channels defined somewhere else but I didn't include that to simplify this. So that is why the same ID cannot be followed by the same ID as displayed in the outcome.

Comment: I did ont mean that kind of details. However, I mean how we know what is the correct ordering that should be given. From your sample output the patterns we can extract we do not know if they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop is over `i`.  Your inner loop is over `ii` (bad names, by the way).  That means `ii` changes faster, and you're using it for the `y` offset of your boxes and text, which means that your count id will be changing up the y direction.  Just change the order of `i` and `ii` in the `plot` and `text` calls.

This would be more obvious if you used loop variables `x` and `y`, for example.

Here are a few other debugging tips that will help you figure out similar things in the future:

- Just print the values of i, ii, and your text, and the order will be obvious to you.
- Simplify some parts of the code to see how the behavior changes.  For example, change one of the `for` loops to 1:1 to produce only a single row or column.
- Change the text you're printing to some intermediate value that helps you debug.  For example, `count`, or `i`, or `ii`.